# GCM and a change of SIM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

If a device is successfully registered with the GCM server and is receiving messages, then if the SIM is changed in the device, will it still receive messages addressed to the reg_id?

I guess this question could be rephrased as 'by what unique key does GCM identify a device? -Does the key include the phone number?'

Comment: no i doesnt include the phone number since many sim cards dont have included the phone number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know GCM `reg_id` based on device/account and application package/context. And it's not associated with sim card. (GCM messaging work's even on emulator)

GCM reg_id can change only if google decide to change it for some reason or when user  [updates app (link)](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/adv.html#reg-state)  to new version.

Comment: Thinking about it, this answer makes sense, as I know my GCM app works on both my phone and on the emulator.